# Find $x$ and $y$ where $ax - by = c$ and $x + y$ is minimum.

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

How can I find out the natural numbers $x$ and $y$, such that

$$ax - by = c$$

and $x + y$ is minimum? $a, b, c$ are given integers.

---

example: $a = 2, b = 2, c = -2$.

$$2x - 2y = -2$$

$$ans: (x = 0, y = 1)$$

---

Also, how can I know when it is impossible? I guess it's when $c$ is not divisible by $LCD(a, b)$. Is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation $ax - b y = c$ (where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $c$ is an integer) has natural number solutions if and only if $GCD(a,b) \mid c$.  Obviously this is necessary as $ax-by$ is divisible by that GCD.  To see it is sufficient: if the GCD is $g$, $a x - b y = g$ has
integer solutions by [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), and you can then multiply by $c/g$ to get a solution of $ax - b y = c$.  Note that if $(x,y)$ is an integer solution, so is $(x+kb/g, y+ka/g)$ for any $k$, so for suitable $k$ you'll have a natural number solution.
Moreover, these are all the solutions.  So to find the natural number solution with the least $x+y$, find $k$ so that $x+kb/g \ge 0$ and $y+ka/g \ge 0$ but $\min(x+(k-1)b/g, y+(k-1)a/g) < 0$.